# show all files in a directory on a page

Tags: php, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP list all files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826963/php-list-all-files-in-directory)

ive got a cron job running creating .xls files every 24hrs, they are creating them in a directory on my site called www.mysite.com/sheets

what i want to do is make a webpage where i can go to and see all the .xls files in that directory and download the ones i was instead of having to download them using an ftp client.

Is there a name for this sort of thing ? what would i write it in ? i was thinking i could do it in php by echoing the folders contents, would that work ?

cheers

Comment: perhaps you are looking for scandir function of php.. [Read Description From php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP list all files in directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826963/php-list-all-files-in-directory), [PHP - Code to traverse a directory and get all the files(images)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608202/php-code-to-traverse-a-directory-and-get-all-the-filesimages), and many many other identical questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could activate directory listing within your webserver, or you can use a function like glob("*.xls") to list the files and echo their path on the webserver or you can send a file to the browser like this:

```
<?php
$filename = "path/to/your/file.xls";
$real_filename = "file.xls";
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: none');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="' . $real_filename . '"');    
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $real_filename);                
$size = @filesize($filename);
if ($size > 0) {
    header('Content-length: '.$size);
} else {
    header('Content-length: '.@strlen(@file_get_contents($filename)));
}
readfile($filename);
exit;
?>
```

If you want to list a directory use this:

```
$handle = opendir("./");
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    $fileinfo = pathinfo($file);
    if (strtolower($fileinfo[extension]) == "xls") {
        echo $file;    
    }
}
closedir($handle);
```

Or this:

```
foreach (glob("*.[xX][lL][sS]") as $filename) {
    echo $filename;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [glob](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)() plus some filtering for xls files.

```
glob("*.xls")
```

Comment: thanks, 

do you know where in this script i would put that ?


<?php
  $cwd = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $cwd = substr($cwd, 0, strrpos($cwd, '/' + 1));

  function paintUndersideOfFox($c) {
    global $cwd;
    echo('<ul class="dirlist">');
    $d = opendir($c);
    while($f = readdir($d)) {
      if(strpos($f, '.') === 0) continue;
      $ff = $c . '/' . $f;
      echo('<li><a href="' . $cwd . $ff . '">' . $ff . '</a></li>');
      if(is_dir($ff)) paintUndersideOfFox($ff);
    }
    echo('</ul>');
  }

  paintUndersideOfFox('.');
?>

Answer (score 0):

Potentially useful resources (in order of preference):

- **Manual**

  - http://php.net/filesystemiterator
  - http://php.net/glob
  - http://php.net/scandir
  - http://php.net/opendir
  - http://php.net/function.dir

Comment: thanks, 

I've found this script any idea how id change it to only show the .xls files ?

<?php
  $cwd = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $cwd = substr($cwd, 0, strrpos($cwd, '/' + 1));

  function paintUndersideOfFox($c) {
    global $cwd;
    echo('<ul class="dirlist">');
    $d = opendir($c);
    while($f = readdir($d)) {
      if(strpos($f, '.') === 0) continue;
      $ff = $c . '/' . $f;
      echo('<li><a href="' . $cwd . $ff . '">' . $ff . '</a></li>');
      if(is_dir($ff)) paintUndersideOfFox($ff);
    }
    echo('</ul>');
  }

  paintUndersideOfFox('.');
?>

Comment: I'm not a fix-your-script kind of guy. Please take the time to read the resources available, and the many, many identical questions here on SO.