# php change quality of all image recursively

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

I have a folder photo, with photos of different size and quality. They are all jpg

I want to go through all of them and reduce jpg quality to 80. Without changing the dimension and name. Then save them to the same folder.

Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: There's a function to scan a directory recursively in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608202/php-code-to-traverse-a-directory-and-get-all-the-filesimages/3608218#3608218

Answer (score 1):

It's easy if you're using Linux. Run the following script inside the directory with a photos:

```
<?php
    shell_exec('for i in *jpg; do convert -quality 80 $i s$i; mv s$i $i; done');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using this function......

function convertPNGto8bitPNG($sourcePath, $destPath) { 
    $srcimage = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourcePath);
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($sourcePath);
    $img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $bga = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagecolortransparent($img, $bga);
    imagefill($img, 0, 0, $bga);
    imagecopy($img, $srcimage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
    imagetruecolortopalette($img, false, 255);
    imagesavealpha($img, true);
    imagejpeg($img, $destPath);
    imagedestroy($img);
}

it will reduce image quality..

to call this function ::::  convertPNGto8bitPNG('a.jpg', 'a1.jpg');

here u will see from a.jpg you will get a1.jpg in the same folder...
but as per your requirement that , image must b with same name you have to use

convertPNGto8bitPNG('a.jpg', 'a.jpg');

so it will replace that image...

now code for all image in a folder

```
     $directory = "img1/";

    //get all image files with a .jpg extension.
    $images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

    //print each file name
    foreach($images as $image)
    {
      //echo $image;          
      convertPNGto8bitPNG($image, $image);
    }
```

here my directory is img1...
you change according to you.

**so final code is..::**

function convertPNGto8bitPNG($sourcePath, $destPath) { 
    $srcimage = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourcePath);
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($sourcePath);
    $img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $bga = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagecolortransparent($img, $bga);
    imagefill($img, 0, 0, $bga);
    imagecopy($img, $srcimage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
    imagetruecolortopalette($img, false, 255);
    imagesavealpha($img, true);
    imagejpeg($img, $destPath);
    imagedestroy($img);
}

```
     $directory = "img1/"; // change according to your dorectory name

    //get all image files with a .jpg extension.
    $images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

    //convert each file
    foreach($images as $image)
    {
      //echo $image;          
      convertPNGto8bitPNG($image, $image);
    }
```

NOTE ::: one more thing i want to tell is you will try to reduce quality more than image capacity it will give blank output
means for this code to be run u must have image with little high quality
otherwise you have to put some conditions

Answer (score 0):

With ImageMagick, simply use the `mogrify`; which, will overwrite existing images with updated quality

```sh
mogrify -quality 80 *.jpg
```

If you're install of PHP support [Execution Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php), just wrap the above commands in single back quotes.

```php
`mogrify -quality 80 *.jpg`
```

Or simply use the [Imagick](http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick) package, if available.

```php
$images = glob('*.jpg');
foreach($images as $image)
{
    $imgObj = new Imagick($image);
    $imgObj->setImageCompressionQuality(80);
    $imgObj->writeImage($image);
}
```