# Create a Sharepoint page from HTML file with images

Tags: html, image, sharepoint, upload

I'm trying to create an editable page in Sharepoint.  I already have the page in HTML (it's quite large) and it has many images in it.  Previously I have just created a new page in sharepoint and pasted the HTML source in, the uploaded/inserted the images manually, one at a time.

Unfortunately, I am not able to do this in a reasonable amount of time since there are many images this HTML file is using.

So, I want an editable Sharepoint page that keeps the images intact from a directory that looks like this:
thepage.html

1.png

2.png

...

...

...

343.png

etc

Any ideas?

EDIT: For more clarity - this is a specifications document in HTML form, so it has a lot of text and header integrated with images.  I'd like it to be converted to an actual Sharepoint Page that is editable from Sharepoint's interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems best here to use a low-tech solution, some HTML editing and use the best way for you to upload multiple files.

Assuming

```
C:\mypage
    -> \page.html
    -> \images\1.png
    -> \images\2.png
    ...
    -> \images\100.png
```

Via the UI

- Go to a Document or Image library, and use the "Upload Multiple files/images" (this only appears on Internet Explorer)
- Lets say you uploaded it to //sharepoint/myimages
- Create a new content page (say an Article page, or WebPart Page with a Content Editor WebPart)
- Lets say your page resides now at //sharepoint/pages/mypage.aspx
- Change your html to point from `<img src="images/1.png" />` to `<img src="../myimages/1.png" />`
- Edit the HTML for your newly created page (Ribbon > Edit HTML Source), paste your HTML code

Via SharePoint Designer

- Drag and Drop all the images in your desired location
- repeat the HTML steps above

To replace text in bulk, SharePoint Designer, your favorite HTML editor or event Notepad can do that well using the CTRL+H menu / Edit > Find & Replace options.

NOTE: the //sharepoint address up there is the http url for your site, SO won't let me use a full fake address as a sample.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the answer is "hack it, this functionality isn't available in sharepoint" but I appreciate the concise and effective answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. From IE or from Word, save the page as a complete webpage so it creates an HTML file plus a folder with the images.
2. In network places, create web folder (WebDAV) pointing to Sharepoint. This way, you can access it from the file system in Explorer.
3. Open your new network place, navigate to the library where you want your HTML file to be, and drag-n-drop the file and folder into there.

The file then will be visible in browser, with the pictures, but the folder will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly your question. You can use this post answer to load list of images by javascript and php -> 
[Load list of image from folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758594/load-list-of-image-from-folder).
Upload files to Share Point server and use that folder.

Or you can dynamically write c# code to read Share Point folder and display images.

Comment: Thanks Drasius!   I'm not looking for a simple image list in this case, this is a large amount of documentation.   So there will be text, header, content as well as the images that will need to displayed in that document in the relevant sections.